# Uploading Image File to File Manager in a Remote Server using MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, file-upload

I want to upload images to a file manager in a remote server. I do not know how to get the physical path of the image.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + x.FileName);
Server.MapPath(x.FileName));`

All these return the virtual path of the image. Does this mean that I have to save the image locally in the application folder first before uploading the image to the remote server using FTP?

Some say that due to security reasons, one cannot have access to the physical path of the image saved locally. So, how can I upload an image from client side if this web application is to be published to cloud?

Thank in advance!

This is the exception thrown.

**Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
Server Response Dude : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
'C:\Users\Fed\source\repos\GreatGit\GreatWeb\P1011559.JPG'.**

My physical image path is
`C:\Users\Fed\Pictures\June 2019\P1011559.JPG.`

Comment: Can you share the code of uploading three file to FTP server? Are you getting file from client as HttpPostedFile?

Comment: Yes, as a HttpPostedFile.

Comment: Can you share the code of uploading the file to FTP server?

Comment: I directly converted the image to bytes array and send it via FTP. Thanks for the help!